# Creating a regular expression that will search for strings converted to 12 digit hex values

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regexp that will search for all 12 digit hex values in a file. For example: string 448699 => hex 343438363939. The regexp that I have now is:

```
(r'3[0-9]\d{10}')
```

it matches the first character to 3 the second 0-9 and the next 10 are any random digits. The hex above is 12 digits and starting with the first character, every other character is a 3. How would I express this with regexp. I was thinking along the lines of the following, but not sure:

```
(r'3[0-9]3[0-9]3[0-9]3[0-9]3[0-9]3[0-9]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Confusion reigns supreme ...**

If you want to match the result of converting **ANY** 6-byte sequence to a 12-hex-digit string (what you asked for), you need `[0-9a-fA-F]{12}`.

If you want to match the result of converting a 6-byte sequence of **ASCII decimal digits** to a 12-hex-digit string (what your sample code indicates), you need `(?:3[0-9]){6}`.

Nitpick: You should **NOT** use `\d` as if you are using Unicode it will pick up any non-ASCII decimal digits, which are NOT hex digits (over 300 possibilities).

The suggestion `(3[0-9a-fA-F]){6}` detects 6-byte sequences of bytes drawn from `0123456789:;<=>?` which is unlikely to be what you want.

**Update** with request for clarification.

Please consider the following and let us know which pattern is actually finding what you want it to find, and is not letting "false positives" through the gate.

```
>>> import re, binascii
>>> originals = ('123456', 'FOOBAR', ':;<=>?')
>>> data = ' '.join(map(binascii.hexlify, originals))
>>> print data
313233343536 464f4f424152 3a3b3c3d3e3f
>>> for pattern in (r'(?:3\d){6}', r'(3[0-9a-fA-F]){6}',
...             r'(?:3[0-9a-fA-F]){6}', r'[0-9a-fA-F]{12}'):
...     print repr(pattern), re.findall(pattern, data)
...
'(?:3\\d){6}' ['313233343536']
'(3[0-9a-fA-F]){6}' ['36', '3f']
'(?:3[0-9a-fA-F]){6}' ['313233343536', '3a3b3c3d3e3f']
'[0-9a-fA-F]{12}' ['313233343536', '464f4f424152', '3a3b3c3d3e3f']
```

Comment: I really appreciate the clarification. I can see that I need to spend some time with regexp ... I'm still trying to understand how/why [0-9a-fA-F]{12} works, but it does!

Comment: @user706808: Please clarify "works". Please clarify which of the 3 above possibilities you want. Obviously you want "3031323435" to match. What about "3a3b3c3d3e3f"? What about "ffffffffffff"?

Comment: I can think a bit more clearly this morning ... long week. After spending some time with the regex, I found that the regex needs to find the string (when x = 0-9): 3x3x3x3x3x3x .... This is the pattern that could be found in the log file when I convert the first 6 digits of a 16 digit number on a .... The device that reads the number takes the sequence and converts it into hex in the form of the original number, with a 3 now prefacing the original number and every other digit of that number thereafter(hex). I'm verifying that the number does not show up in the clear in logs.

Comment: @Mike Pennington - comment added.

Answer (score 3):

You're really close. The pattern you want is:

```
(r'(?:3\d){6}')
```

Edit - As Mike Pennington pointed out, hex numbers can include letters A-F. I wasn't actually sure of the purpose of the "every other digit is 3" rule, so I left the rules as you described them.

Comment: @Justin Morgan This regexp only returns the first 2 digits. I was looking to find patterns like: 12 digits long and x = 0-9    => 3x3x3x3x3x3x

Comment: @user706808 - It should return the full 12-digit sequence. You may be looking at the capture group, which will contain each "3x" pair. I changed it to a non-capturing group, try it now. You can also test it here: http://rubular.com/r/QUeiOqjNB6 and a version that accepts hexadecimal digits A-F: http://rubular.com/r/6yorlzZzZM (note the case-insensitivity flag).

Comment: @Justin Morgan That did it ... I've got to take the time to learn regexp. They are so powerful! What did you mean by capture group vs non-capturing group?

Comment: @user706808 - Normally, when you wrap parentheses around a sub-pattern in regex, the engine saves whatever matches that sub-pattern for later. It's a little hard to explain; check out this [reference info on grouping and backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: @Justin Morgan - I'm curious about one other thing: if there is an ascii value (eg. 115 15 110 110) in a file, another regexp I'm using will not find it, unless I remove the white space from between the string. Realistically, this could occur in log files. Can regxp ignore whitespace only?

Comment: @user706808 - `\s` will match whitespace, though how you apply it in your pattern will depend on the rest of the regex. You could also just strip out all spaces from the string with normal string manipulation functions, then run regex on the result.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there... since hex can have `a-f` you need to include those...

```
(r'(3[0-9a-fA-F]){6}')
```

Comment: @Mike Pennington: `binascii.hexlify(':;<=>?')` produces `'3a3b3c3d3e3f'` which is matched by your answer ... please reconsider.

Comment: @John Machin, please clarify what the problem is... Quoting the OP, `The hex above is 12 digits and starting with the first character, every other character is a 3. How would I express this with regexp.`  The wording is a little unclear, but the string you gave me seems to fit the description in the OP's comment.  Furthermore, he already accepted an answer similar to mine and in fact they said they actually needed my answer... so the point is??

Comment: @Mike Pennington: See my answer. The wording is very unclear. You have picked the least plausible out of 3 possibilities.

Comment: @John Machin, let me quote the OP, `I'm still trying to understand how/why [0-9a-fA-F]{12} works, but it does!`.  Could we please discuss this with him first?

Comment: @Mike Pennington: Oh indeed it would, which is why I catalogued all three possibilities in my answer -- however the OP changed his accepted answer to mine and then back again without any attempt at clarifying what he really wanted.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but it. like all the others, needs some `\b` anchors to prevent it from matching: `313233343536ABCDEF1234567890`

Comment: @Ridgerunner, interesting point; however, I'm still not sure we actually know the exact requirements of the OP.